# Detecting real mobile device vs. dev tools emulation

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to trigger a function on resizing, but only on the desktop when you use dev tools to emulate a different device. (The issue is that my code is used to load different video sources at different screen sizes and in chrome on mobile devices, the navbar hiding as you scroll down triggers the resize even, thus reloading the video)

To that end, I'm trying to figure out a way to differentiate between genuine mobile devices and dev tools emulations of them.

I'm trying to use this code:

```js
     var isMobile = false; //initiate as false
// device detection
if(/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|ipad|iris|kindle|Android|Silk|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino/i.test(navigator.userAgent) 
    || /1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(navigator.userAgent.substr(0,4))) { 
    isMobile = true;
}
     console.log('is mobile='+isMobile);
```

But the dev tools' mobile device emulations are all detected as mobile and I can't think of a way around it.

Comment: I would be tempted to go at this from a different angle and figure out why the navbar triggers a resize event and try to prevent it from doing so.

Comment: There's no guarantee that anything you use now to detect mobile emulation vs true mobile will continue to work in the future unless you find some documentation to the contrary

Answer (score 3):

These emulation dev tools are specifically designed to make everything look the same as a real device.
However, some things are easy to fake than others. User-Agent is easy, so that's not going to be a route to identifying an emulator. (Same goes for the new [User Agent Client Hints](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/User-Agent_Client_Hints_API))

Most libraries for device detection will make use of User-Agent and similar HTTP headers, so they also generally won't be able to tell you about dev tools emulators.

You'll need to look at other outputs that are harder to fake. For example, if you look at the 'unmasked vendor' and 'unmasked renderer' values from webgl, you'll see that they are different to what they would be on a real device.

You can see these values [here](https://webglreport.com/) or use the following snippet:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var gl = canvas.getContext('webgl');

var debugInfo = gl.getExtension('WEBGL_debug_renderer_info');
var vendor = gl.getParameter(debugInfo.UNMASKED_VENDOR_WEBGL);
var renderer = gl.getParameter(debugInfo.UNMASKED_RENDERER_WEBGL);

console.log(vendor);
console.log(renderer);
```

You'll need to do some research to verify if something like this would work for all browsers and all mobile OS's, or if several different approaches are required. I think it should be possible to build something with reasonable accuracy though.

Comment: There's probably no guarantee that this won't be "fixed" in the future either.