# Detecting if a device is an Android

Tags: javascript, android

I want to be able to detect if the device my React app is running on is an Android. I have tried the two implementations below, but whenever I open the developer tools, the check is fooled and thinks the computer is an Android device. Is there a way around this?

```
import { UAParser } from "ua-parser-js";

export function isAndroidDevice() {
  const parser = new UAParser();
  const uaResult = parser.getResult();
  return !!uaResult.os.name?.includes("Android");
}
```

```
  const isAndroidDevice = () => {
    const userAgent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
    return userAgent.includes('android');
  };
```

Comment: *”but whenever I open the developer tools”* could it be that the app then opens in one of dev tools browser simulators?

Comment: Yes, it's opening in a browser simulator for an Android phone. I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to detect that the actual device is a computer.

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: Using Google Chrome

Comment: You want to detect android, you run the code in android (simulator) and successfully detected it is android. Everything sounds good. Your question is more like "How to identify if the app is running in an android simulator but not a real android device".

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71886023/16770846) answer your question?

Comment: chk this old question:https://stackoverflow.com/a/21742107/14144599